# compile web service tfs build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfs-2015

I'm using `tfs 2015.3` and I'm trying to compile a web service project (.asmx).

Now, my build failed because of this error: `It is an error to user asection registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level`

I looked online for solutions and found that there is a problem at the build when 2 `web.config` is at the same project (one at the root and one is somewhere at the project's folders). Then I saw that a folder named `PrecompileWeb` was created with content of another project from the solution.

I tried to build the project at `vs2013/2015` and the folder does not get created, as opposed to with `msbuild` (which `tfs` probably uses).

How can I prevent this folder from appearing? I saw a solution that suggested giving a property of `'/p:PreBuildEvent='` or something like that, but it's not working.

Comment: What msbuild parameters you add in TFS Visual Studio Build task? To prevent the `PrecompileWeb`, you could refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805055/publish-artifacts-for-website-goes-to-precompiledweb/43841775#43841775

Comment: The params are platform:any CPU and configuration:release. Right now I'm not using deploy, so I don't know if the link is helping me

Comment: Without some other msbuild parameters?

Comment: I just edit my command, sorry

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT i saw the link again and i dont understand why adding  /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 is the solution

Comment: Sorry that I didn't find what you edited. And the key point of  link is to build the `website.publishproj`file not the `***.sln` file.

Comment: Did you succeed to prevent the 'Precompileweb' to generate? Does the error still exists?

Comment: @Tingting09292-MSFT  It works!  Thank you very much. But my tfs build is still not working, I think it's because my lack of knowledge working with publish

Comment: You'd better give me a screenshot of your Visual Studio Build Tasks and what values you put for the parameters.