# Azure DevOps Continuous Integration with asp.net website project instead of web application

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I have a hard requirement from the developer to use a website project instead of a web app project for a .net deployment.  I am able to connect and use continuous integration just fine with a web app project, but when using website, it fails to find the compiled files for deployment:

```
#[debug]check path : D:\a\_tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts_2ff763a7-ce83-4e1f-bc89-
0ae63477cebe\1.142.2\task.json
##[debug]set resource file to: D:\a\_tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts_2ff763a7-ce83-4e1f-bc89-0ae63477cebe\1.142.2\task.json
##[debug]system.culture=en-US
##[debug]PathtoPublish=D:\a\1\a
##[debug]check path : D:\a\1\a
##[debug]ArtifactName=drop
##[debug]ArtifactType=Container
##[debug]system.hostType=build
##[warning]Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.
```

Looking at the build process, it's compiling a copy of the deployment to the PrecompiledWeb folder instead of the debug folder, which seems to explain why it cannot find the results.  Has anyone had luck deploying with a website project or have you run into the issue above?

Comment: Please include details about your config files ex. the csproj, startup etc...

Comment: I hope you can build your project now. Could you please post your yaml code or classical editor screenshot for reference? I really need help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Azure DevOps Continuous Integration with asp.net website project instead of web application

Since the project is asp.net website, you may need use the `website.publishproj` file instead of the `.sln` file when you publish the asp.net website project with MSBuild.

The command line like:

```
msbuild.exe "<PathToTheFile>\website.publishproj" /p:deployOnBuild=true /p:publishProfile=WebsiteTestDemo /p:VisualStudioVersion=1x.0
```

With this setting, MSBuild does not create the `PrecompiledWeb` folder and the publish uses the setting in the profile.

Check [my previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805055/publish-artifacts-for-website-goes-to-precompiledweb/43841775#43841775) for some more details.

> The website project the publish process is not plumbed into the build
>   process. For website project since there is no formal build process
>   there was nothing for us to really extend.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this help me get it published.

Comment: Please also refer the below question regarding TFVC deployment and answer for the scenario. Thanks!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76216606/how-to-deploy-the-tfvc-asp-net-website-code-to-the-azure-app-services-using-azu

Comment: In my project there is no 'website.publishproj'  file as you mentioned so I need your help to build the project please see the above question and answer. Thanks!