# MSbuild Website Not Publishing to Local Directory

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, build, msbuild

I need to publish a .NET web site project to a local directory. The web site project is part of a solution that also contains a web app. The **Publish Web App** option in Visual Studio publishes the web site to the directory without issue, however I am unable to publish the site through msbuild.

My msbuild command

```
msbuild "C:\...\ProjectName\website.publishproj" /p:deployOnBuild=true /p:publishProfile=Dev /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=false /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem
```

The dev.pubxml publish profile I am referencing is:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\FolderLocation</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>.vs</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Currently the web site is not publishing to `C:\FolderLocation` but instead appears to publish to `ProjectName\PrecompiledWeb\localhost_51636`. Changing the output directory via `/p:OutDir=C:\FolderLocation` publishes the *web app* to the correct location, however it does not publish the *web site*. I have also tried both `/p:PublishDestination` and `/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation` msbuild arguments however the original issue remains.

I have referenced [Publish Artifacts for website goes to PrecompiledWeb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805055/publish-artifacts-for-website-goes-to-precompiledweb/43841775#43841775) and many other resources. My eventual goal is to setup CI through Azure Devops for the entire legacy .NET website project.

Comment: Where do you run the msbuild? I mean, do you use developer command prompt for vs2015 or use 'cmd+msbuild.exe under v4.0.30319' folder? Cause I've test with leo's answer, and that command works well on my side with VS2015 website.

Comment: Hi friend, when you mentioned "publish the site through msbuild", do you mean the issue occurs when using the msbuild tool locally without TFS.

Comment: Hi Lance. I am running msbuild locally from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`. When I use Leo's command, the command completes but it does not publish to the directory listed in my dev.pubxml publish profile. It appears to be publishing to `ProjectName\PrecompiledWeb\localhost_51636` instead.

Comment: Hi, friend, try open the developer coomand compt for vs2015, and type the command there. I've seen many issues with the msbuild.exe under v4.0.30319 folder. Please try the C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe.(This version is more suitable for you)

Comment: And for leo's command. We all use the developer command prompt to run the command, and we all succeed. (Instead of v4.0.30319, I think it's not latest version for vs2015)

Comment: Try using command: msbuild ... /p:publishUrl=C:\FolderLocation. I doubt whether the content of publish profile is read, so you can use this property to try to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

With TFS - it is using MSBUILD under the covers and we need this parameter to write to a directory for artifacts to be pulled from

/p:OutDir=$(build.StagingDirectory)

You are telling it only about the Publish Project part - see if putting your SLN file there at the first parameter solves it and does all of them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have also tried building the .SLN instead, however this creates a new issue. The web app is published to `C:\FolderLocation\Projectname\_PublishedWebsites` and the web site becomes published to a new directory location `C:\ProjectName_PublishedWebsites`.

Comment: Yes - and then you navigate down that structure for what you want to be in your virtual directory and push it in.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I am able to start the website from within that directory. I am still confused why msbuild ignores the output directory from `dev.pubxml` using the original command I linked to above. To setup a CI server using the method you've provided would require additional copy commands and be messy to automate.

Comment: Looks like you need to be on Visual Studio version 15.2 (Visual Studio 2017 update 2) based on this discussion https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1901